# JMeter Non GUI Test Execution

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmx

I'm executing multiple scripts for 1 hr in Non GUI Mode.

Test Scripts:- Script1 Script2 Script3

Test Execution Approach :- Keeping 3 thread groups in one script and giving equal number of users in Non GUI mode.

JMeter version 4.0

Number of Samples are differing with respect to the scenarios. I need equal distribution for all 3 scenarios. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the fix loop count in all 3 thread groups something like 1000 or 10000 depend on your scenario. Do not use time duration here as you want jmeter to stop after all execution is completed.

Secondly, you can use "Througput Controller" for executing samplers for a fix number of times.

Hope it help.